# How to spread out a beam from a moving head

Tags: optics

I have a couple of small moving heads [available here](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/Eurolite-LED-TMH-8-Moving-Head-Spot-10W-CREE-Quadcolor-QCL-LED-RGBW-DHL-Paket-/271219356511) 
I'm using them for the band to focus on particular musicians sometimes and I would like to be able to make the beam angle wider. 
Sometimes I have them mounted about 20feet away and the beam angle is perfect when I want to spotlight a  single musician, but most of the time they are mounted at our feet only five feet away and the beam angle is too narrow to cover the whole musician (or even instrument). 
I have tried placing several different camera lenses in from of the moving heads to see if I can spread out the beam angle but all they seem to do is make them out of focus. 
The moving heads have several gobos with designs that are projected. I plan on making some custom laser printed band logo gobos as well so I would like to keep the "focus" of these gobos but I just want to be able to make the beam angle bigger. 
I opened up the fixture and it seems there is three lenses:
LED --> Small lens --> rotating gobo--> sliding focusing lens -->Final Lens
All the lenses seem to be concave.

My question is: Can I remove/move one of these lenses to significantly change the beam angle, or can I attach an extra lens/2 lenses to the outside instead?
  I'd like to be able to go back to factory beam angle when necessary for some gigs so a clip on lens on the outside would be preferable but it couldn't be too heavy as I estimate that the motors on the moving head can't lift more than an extra 200g weight on the front of the existing lens.

What do you think?

Comment: While this is an engineering question, I would suggest that you try to find suitable Fresnel lenses, which are thin, light, and should be able to get the job done.

Comment: Interesting idea, but wouldn't fresnel lenses pretty much destroy the integrity of the projected logo? I assumed these were only used for lighthouses and such rather than projectors.

Comment: Oops, didn't catch that part, I am afraid. No, you don't want to project with anything but optics made for projection and the results with a Fresnel lens would be poor.

Comment: There are some clip on wide angle lens adapters for SLR cameras that might work. There not designed to do this, so I'd try one of the cheap ones.